# Error: Cannot find module 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin'

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm writing e2e tests using Protractor integrated with Cucumber.
I wanted to be able to generate HTML reports for my tests so I decided to use the following plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin

I've installed it as per description, also added necessary options to my protractor conf.js file:

```
plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin',
    options:{
        automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
        removeExistingJsonReportFile: true
    }
}]
```

However, when I run my tests, I get this Error: Cannot find module 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin'
I've double checked and protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin is present in my node-modules folder.
When I comment out the above code, the test passes without errors.

My Protractor version is 5.3.2, protractor-cucumber-framework version: 5.0.0 and protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin version is 1.7.0

Edit:
Here's my full config file:

```
exports.config = {
directConnect: true,
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
    }
},
specs: [
    'features/**/home.feature'
],
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
cucumberOpts: {
    require: ['specs/test_spec.js'],
    format: 'json:results.json',
},
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronisation = true;
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000);
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
},
params: {
    username: 'Admin',
    password: 'Password',
},
plugins: [{
package: 'protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin',
    options:{
    automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
    removeExistingJsonReportFile: true,
    }
}],
getPageTimeout: 30000,
```

}

Comment: Can you post your full config file please.

Comment: create an new file: `test.js`in same folder where protractor conf.js inside, write this line into new file `var a = require('protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin');`, then run the new file: `node test.js`.  If report same problem, means the plugin need to reinstall to get an integral installation.

Comment: Thanks, I created the file as you described it above, and when I ran it in the console, nothing happened, but also no errors were displayed.
But still, my problem is not solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. Either you must initialize your package.json or change this to your config, at the plugins section:

```
package: require.resolve('protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin');
```

Comment: Could you please "accept" and "like" the answer? It will help my reputation. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I just did :)